# How to verify a DSA signature given (R,S) pair in Java?

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, dsa

I am developing a Java (JDK 1.8) application using standard (built in) DSA classes in order to verify digital signatures.

I have data files and the expected signatures stored in text files as shown below:

```
// Signature part R:
4226 3F05 F103 E3BE 59BF 3903 37F8 0375 8802 5D8F.
// Signature part S:
AF21 15B0 16E4 1761 75B8 C7D4 F877 5AB7 26BB AE72.
```

Note that the signature is expressed in the form of (R,S) pair as described in the FIPS 186-3 NIST Standard.

In order to verify the signature I am calling the method verify(byte[] signature) from java.security.Signature. This method expects a byte array that represents the signature to be verified. However, I do not know how to convert the (R,S) pair into a byte array. Therefore I am not able to verify the signature.

So, I would like to know:

1) Is there a way of converting (R, S) pair into a DSA byte array signature as expected by the verify() method?; Or,

2) Is there a way of getting the R and S values from the Java Signature instance class so that I can compare these values to the ones I have?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: the solution proposed by @dave_thompson_085 worked pretty well! See below the complete source code:

```
// read DSA parameters from file or other means
BigInteger r = new BigInteger(...);
BigInteger s = new BigInteger(...);
BigInteger p = new BigInteger(...);
BigInteger q = new BigInteger(...);
BigInteger g = new BigInteger(...);
BigInteger y = new BigInteger(...);

// get the public key
KeySpec publicKeySpec = new DSAPublicKeySpec(y, p, q, g);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);  

// read the input file to be checked and update signature
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
signature.initVerify(publicKey);
File inputFile = new File(...);
try (BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile))) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (is.available() != 0) {
        int len = is.read(buffer);
        signature.update(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}

// convert (r, s) to ASN.1 DER encoding
// assuming you have r and s as !!positive!! BigIntegers
// (if you have unsigned byte[] as shown in your Q, 
// use BigInteger r = new BigInteger (1, bytes) etc.
byte[] rb = r.toByteArray();
byte[] sb = s.toByteArray(); // sign-padded if necessary
// these lines are more verbose than necessary to show the structure
// compiler will fold or you can do so yourself 
int off = (2 + 2) + rb.length;
int tot = off + (2 - 2) + sb.length;
byte[] der = new byte[tot + 2];
der[0] = 0x30;
der[1] = (byte) (tot & 0xff);
der[2 + 0] = 0x02;
der[2 + 1] = (byte) (rb.length & 0xff);
System.arraycopy(rb, 0, der, 2 + 2, rb.length);
der[off + 0] = 0x02;
der[off + 1] = (byte) (sb.length & 0xff);
System.arraycopy(sb, 0, der, off + 2, sb.length);

// verifies if the signature is valid
boolean isValid = signature.verify(des);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1A. The form expected by normal Java crypto (and most but not all other uses of DSA, and also ECDSA) is an **ASN.1 DER encoding**. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1797/12642 explains what the difficulties are but doesn't quite tell you how to do it.

1B. If you have or can install [the BouncyCastle cryptoprovider](http://www.bouncycastle.org) jar, it contains a whole set of ASN.1 routines. Or easier it also contains 
a low-level primitive `org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.DSASigner` with `init` and `verifySignature(byte[], BigInteger, BigInteger)` accessible. (But this primitive does not do the hash, so do that yourself first.)

1C. If you must do it yourself with standard crypto:

```
// assuming you have r and s as !!positive!! BigIntegers
// (if you have unsigned byte[] as shown in your Q, 
// use BigInteger r = new BigInteger (1, bytes) etc.

byte[] rb = r.toByteArray(), sb = s.toByteArray(); // sign-padded if necessary
// these lines are more verbose than necessary to show the structure
// compiler will fold or you can do so yourself 
int off = (2+2)+rb.length, tot = off+(2-2)+sb.length;
byte[] der = new byte[tot+2];
der[0] = 0x30; der[1] = tot;
der[2+0] = 0x02; der[2+1] = rb.length; System.arraycopy(rb,0, der,2+2, rb.length);
der[off+0] = 0x02; der[off+1] = sb.length; System.arraycopy(sb,0, der,off+2, sb.length);
```

2. You cannot verify a standard DSA signature by comparing r and s. As you should know from reading FIPS186-3 sections 4.5 and 4.6 signatures are randomized; computing two (or more) signatures for the same message gives a different (r,s) pair every time -- unless you repeat enough times to hit the same k, which on average is 2^159 tries for older 1024/160 groups/keys, more for newer/larger ones. If you have a million computers each of which can do a million tries per second, this will still take about 16,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 years.

Comment: Thanks Dave Thompson for your reply.

I do prefer using the built in java.security classes just because I do believe they can manage to solve this issue.

And you are quite right about the impossibility of comparing r and s values to verify the signature. I forgot to mention that I know the issuer´s public key (that is, the p, q, g and y values).

Therefore, is it possible to verify the signature knowing p, q, g, y, r and s values?

Comment: Of course, but you need to build the required `DSAPublicKey` and signature format yourself if you don't want to rely on third party libs.

Comment: Sure, I am doing this:


    // get issuer´s public key
    PublicKey pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA").generatePublic(new DSAPublicKeySpec(y, p, q, g));
    Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA");
    sig.initVerify(pubKey);
    sig.update(...);  // read file to check and call update()
    byte[] sigToVerify = convert(r, s, y, p, q, g,...);  // convert (r,s,...) to the expected format
    boolean verify = sig.verify(sigToVerify);

The problem is that I do not know how to implement the convert() method as shown above. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post. I have not discovered how to format the code yet!

Comment: @MarceloMedeiros META: formatting in comments is very limited, and SX is designed to be Q&A not discussion; excessive comments often get deleted. Add substantial additional details, data, and especially code _to your question_ using the edit button. It's usually nice to mark such changes as 'added' or 'edited', although the system maintains an edit history automatically and can display it on request.

Comment: @MarceloMedeiros: but to the point, you provide p,q,g,y in the DSAPublicKey (or equivalent cert) to `.initVerify`; you provide signature containing r,s and ONLY r.s to `.verify` in the format I showed.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085! Everything is working like a charm!